How do I force z88dk assembler to compile Z80 assembly strictly using Z80 original instructions
I'm using z88dk to compile Z80 assembly code into binary code to be used in a 80s computer.
If I use this kind of assembly code:
public _main            ; This entry point definition is required by
z88dk
_main:
    org 0x0000

    ld hl, 0x8000
    ld a, 1
    add hl, a           ; Not a correct Z80 instruction

... where I use an invalid Z80 instruction add hl, a, and compile it like:
z88dk-z80asm test.asm z88dk-z80asm -b test.o

... and then disassemble the test.bin binary back to assembly language, the assembler seems to have replaced the add hl, a instruction with a call to a subroutine that actually does "add hl, a" with standard Z80 instructions:
0000 ORG_0000:
0000              ld   hl,8000h     ; 32768, -32768
0003              ld   a,01h    ; 1
0005              call .org_0000_l  ; 0008h
0008 .org_0000_l:
0008              push af     
0009              add  a,l    
000A              ld   l,a    
000B              ld   a,h    
000C              adc  a,00h    ; 0
000E              ld   h,a    
000F              pop  af     
0010              ret         

How can I turn this behavior off in z88dk-z80asm or zcc?

I guess issue-2655 - How do I force z88dk assembler to compile Z80 assembly strictly using Z80 original instructions? is yours? :-) I looked at the commit from when they added the z80n extended instructions "add bc|de|hl, a" and it looks like they simply changed it from being an Error to CD @__z80asm__addhla which uses the substitution file (for non-z80n targets only I presume).

What does your research reveal, and why does it not help you? You read the documentation, didn't you?

@thebusybee Yes, I read the documentation and didn't find anything about how to detect this. Of course I can disassemble the compiled binary and detect changes that way, but it does not seem optimal.

@TedLyngmo Yes, correct. :) It seems that it's not possible to turn off this feature.

It seems that it's not possible to turn off this feature, at least for now. However, you can generate the list file (using -l parameter) and scan for a call instruction cd0000 or a longer hex string (4 or 5 bytes) to find out where synthetic instructions are being used.
